# Hive join understanding issue

Tags: sql, hadoop, apache-spark, hive, hdfs

I have created two tables as below in hive

`create table test1(id string)`;

```
create table test2(id string);
```

test1 has values as given below

1

1

test2 has values as given below

1

1

When I am joining these two tables I am getting output with

1

1

1

1

**This is the query used :**

```
select a.id from test1 a,test2 b where a.id=b.id;
```

Please help I expected the output to be as

1

1

I am using cloudera distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better use ANSI join syntax:

```
select a.id 
  from test1 a 
       inner join test2 b on a.id=b.id
```

The expected output cannot be the result of your join because for each `a.id` all matching rows from `a` and `b` are selected. For the first row from `a` it will be two matching rows in `b`. For the second row from `a` it will be also two matching rows from `b`. So it will be four rows totally.

You can apply distinct to the second table before join for example.

```
select a.id 
  from test1 a 
       inner join (select distinct b.id from test2 b) b on a.id=b.id
```

In this case for each row in table `a` it will be single matching row in table `b`.

See this lesson to understand JOINS better: https://www.coursera.org/learn/analytics-mysql/lecture/kydcf/joins-with-many-to-many-relationships-and-duplicates